# How do I update my environment variables on every monitor run?

Tags: json, postman

I am trying to update my variables in between monitor runs. Essentially, I need my collections to speak to each other using environment variables by making my initial value of the variable equal to my current variable (Which is the one that just ran)

```json
    {
    "environment": {
        "name": "NEW",
        "values": [

            {
                "key": "PriorRunObject",
                "value": "{{PriorRunObject}}"
                
            }

          
        ]
    }
}
```

You can see I am "dynamically" referencing my variable in the body of the xml that needs to be placed in the PUT request I am using. I am using the postman PUT Update Environment request to do this.

I also tried the following which did not work:

```json
    {
    "environment": {
        "name": "NEW",
        "values": [

            {
                "key": "PriorRunObject",
                "value": {{PriorRunObject}}
                
            }

          
        ]
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help and/or contribution! :)

Comment: This is what I am trying to do: https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009734013-How-to-Persist-variables-between-monitor-runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. You cannot leave the value field blank. Some of my variables' values were blank and I thought that was ok. It is not. That will throw an error at you.